# Create new key binding for command mode in evil mode

Tags: key-bindings, evil, doom

I am using doom emacs and would like to create a key binding to run the following line so that I don't need to write it every time I want to run a block of code of python

```
:w !python
```

The above line runs python code highlighted in visual mode in the terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cleanest way is to not reuse Evil-specific commands or keystrokes unless absolutely necessary.  Looking at the definition of `:w`, which happens to be the `evil-write` command, one can see that it parses the file name argument and calls `shell-command-on-region` if it starts with a bang.  Here's the equivalent specialized command:

```
(defun my-evil-run-python-region (beg end)
  (interactive "r")
  (if (region-active-p)
      (shell-command-on-region beg end "python")
    (shell-command-on-region (point-min) (point-max) "python")))

(global-set-key (kbd "<F5>") 'my-evil-run-python-region)
```

Comment: I am new to emacs so I spent hours trying to figure this out but with no success.I figured  there must be something I am doing wrong so i wrote my question. I tried your code and it worked. I don't have  enough points to vote for your answer now but should do when I have.  Thank YOU!!

Comment: Thanks. I think you should be able to mark it as preferred answer though, so that the question shows up as solved.

Comment: Done. Thank You!!